# Auto capture image everytime a pothole is detected

Tags: python, opencv

I'm starting to learn Python and I have some code here. This code already works and detects a pothole on the road using my raspberry pi 4. But my problem is that I want to make my camera capture an image every time a pothole is detected. Does anyone know how to do it? Here is the code

Start capturing video input from the camera.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
```

Visualization parameters

```
row_size = 20  # pixels
left_margin = 24  # pixels
text_color = (0, 0, 255)  # red
font_size = 1
font_thickness = 1
fps_avg_frame_count = 10
```

Initialize the object detection model

```
base_options = core.BaseOptions(
    file_name=model, use_coral=enable_edgetpu, num_threads=num_threads)
detection_options = processor.DetectionOptions(
    max_results=3, score_threshold=0.3)
options = vision.ObjectDetectorOptions(
    base_options=base_options, detection_options=detection_options)
detector = vision.ObjectDetector.create_from_options(options)
```

Continuously capture images from the camera and run inference

```
while cap.isOpened():
  success, image = cap.read()
  if not success:
    sys.exit(
        'ERROR: Unable to read from webcam. Please verify your webcam settings.'
    )

  counter += 1
  image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
```

Run object detection estimation using the model.

```
  detection_result = detector.detect(input_tensor)


def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
       formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--model',
      help='Path of the object detection model.',
      required=False,
      default='pothole_label.tflite')
 parser.add_argument(
  '--cameraId', help='Id of camera.', required=False, type=int, default=0)
 parser.add_argument(
  '--frameWidth',
  help='Width of frame to capture from camera.',
  required=False,
  type=int,
  default=640)
 parser.add_argument(
  '--frameHeight',
  help='Height of frame to capture from camera.',
  required=False,
  type=int,
  default=480)
 parser.add_argument(
  '--numThreads',
  help='Number of CPU threads to run the model.',
  required=False,
  type=int,
  default=4)
 parser.add_argument(
  '--enableEdgeTPU',
  help='Whether to run the model on EdgeTPU.',
  action='store_true',
  required=False,
  default=False)
 args = parser.parse_args()

 run(args.model, int(args.cameraId), args.frameWidth, args.frameHeight,
      int(args.numThreads), bool(args.enableEdgeTPU))


 if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: You question is too long to read, please simplify it if you can

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I've already changed it

Comment: By saying *" But my problem is that I want to make my camera capture an image every time a pothole is detected"*, do you mean to save the capture or pop-up on the window with imshow after detecting? Also just curiously asking, how are you detecting the holes on the way ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I train my own dataset using labelImg and google colab. And call the name of my file here 
parser.add_argument(
      '--model',
      help='Path of the object detection model.',
      required=False,
      default='pothole_label.tflite')

Comment: I want to save the captured image containing the pothole after capturing it.

Comment: Then after you detected, you can simply save it to the desired file with the command `cv2.imwrite('path/to/file/img.jpg',frame)`

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk know how to auto-capture an image when the camera is open, but what I want to do is to only capture the image when a pothole is being detected.

Answer (score 0):

You already have all the info you need.
In your case, you want to save the results of your detection.

To generally save, you would save the image from the camera at each frame as such

```
cv2.imwrite(f'{counter}.jpg', image)
```

If you want to filter the results only in the case of detection. Assuming that your `detection_result` is a numpy array:

```
if detection_result.shape[0]:
    cv2.imwrite(f'{counter}.jpg', image)
```

This will check that you have one or more detections and save accordingly.